# Is it possible to use an js-dom-based Enzyme wrapper with react-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I was wondering if have a component that is rendered within an Enzyme js-dom wrapper, I can use react-testing-library with it.  I'd like to drop in the `fireEvent` method in `react-testing-library` instead of Enzyme's `simulate` method.  The wrapper I'd like to use would look something like this:

```js
const wrapper = mount(<App />);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two libraries are not compatible. You can't use one to interact with the other.